# Reading data from serial port (COM3) using pyserial module on Windows XP

Tags: python, usb, windows-xp, pyserial

Before going into the problem, here is some hardware/software information:

Device accessed: Ohaus Scout Pro Digital Weight Machine ([product link](http://www.northshorecare.com/ohaus-scout-pro.html))
Interface used: USB ([product link](http://www.carolina.com/product/702448.do?s_cid=ppc_gl_products))
Serial Port: COM3
OS: WinXP
Python Version: Activestate Python 2.7
pyserial version: 2.5

Python recognized this serial port and had no problems opening it. I am new to python as  well as pyserial. I couldn't figure out how exactly can I read data from the serial port. I used the following code:

```
1 import serial
2 ser=serial.Serial(port='COM3',timeout=3)
3 s=ser.read(100) #reading up to 100 bytes
4 print s
```

This prints nothing. During those 3 seconds timeout, I placed an object on the weighing machine and it showed 100grams on the machine. But, this data is not showing on the computer. How can I read this data using pyserial?

Answer (score 2):

The baudrate is missing. You **must** [specify baudrate](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports). Most serial devices can not tolerate a wrong communication speed.

Comment: The problem was with the actual device. Fixed it by changing its physical settings. Thanks for the help.