# PySerial [Error 5] Access is Denied

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to write a program in Python that will loop to keep checking the serial port (COM4) and print out a message when the character "1" is read from the serial port. I want to send "1" over the serial port from an Arduino gadget upon the push of a button.

However, I get the error "[Error 5]: Access is Denied" when I try to create an instance of a serial object. (It automatically tries to open upon instantiation, which is where the error is, from what I can see from the file in the PySerial package that handles this.)

My code:

```
c = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
while True:
    signal = c.read()
    print signal
    print "running"
    time.sleep(2)
    c.flushOutput()
```

It never gets past the "c = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600), though. That's where the error pops up. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add full call stack of the error message?

Comment: Check if other process is using the com port.

Comment: Access Denied(ERR NO:5) : Already on use error, REQUEST REJECTED (ERR NO:13) : Sytstem Colsed USB or Data Bus PORT (check **power management** settings.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: This is apparently no longer possible in PySerial 3.0.

Under Windows, I've always used the port=<int> approach with success.

I.e. change your code to:

```
c = serial.Serial(3, 9600)
```

Comment: Wow, this works! Thank you so much! Why does this work though? How does the number 3 indicate 'COM4'?

Comment: The port parameter can be either a string or a number. When a number under Windows, it's the zero-based COM port. So, 0 is COM1 and 3 is COM4. It's possible "COM4:" would work also, but I've never tried it.

Comment: Well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602349/problem-reading-data-from-serial-port-com3-using-pyserial-module-on-windows-xp implies that "COM4" should work. Googling turns up potential issues with the names of virtual serial ports. I guess port=<int> works around those naming issues.

Comment: **ValueError: "port" must be None or a string, not <class 'int'>**

Answer (score 8):

For me the solution didn't work but what worked was closing all the applications that were interacting with the given com port.

Comment: Good answer IMO: when developing for Arduino, it's rather common to have the Arduino IDE running, but this makes `serial` unable to access the port.

Comment: Duh! Of course that's what I was missing. You cannot have two applications open a serial port at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Please, take care with the python versions.

From the pyserial manual about: class serial.Serial 
https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#classes

...........

The port is immediately opened on object creation, when a port is given. It is not opened when port is None and a successive call to open() is required.

port is a device name: depending on operating system. e.g. /dev/ttyUSB0 on GNU/Linux or COM3 on Windows.

............

Changed in version 3.0: numbers as port argument are no longer supported

Answer (score 2):

Close your serial monitor, opened from Arduino IDE.

Comment: Closing the serial monitor on the Arduino IDE worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For `Python 2.6` use the zero-based COM port index. For `Python 2.7.x` you can use the full name "COM4". From my experience it's better to use the 2.7 version. Install [Python 2.7.x](http://www.python.org/download/) and [Setup Tools (aka Easy Install)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files). Once you've got this, install pyserial module by typing `easy_install -U pyserial` (see [pyserial installation doc](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial.html)).

*Remember to add python path to `PATH` environmental variable.*

Answer (score 1):

that works with  PORT COM  **N-1**
in python
(N is your number of COM)

Answer (score 0):

```
    At one time, there is only an application that can access one com port. If application A is accessing this com port, application B can not access it. You should do these following steps as below:
    1. Find the application that is accessing this port and then close the connection.
    2. Reconnect your application to this port. You can use the below source code.
    
     port='COM8',
 baudrate = 2400,
 parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
 stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
 bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
 timeout=None
)

while 1:
 x = ser.readline()
 print(x)
```