# Opening multliple ports with pyserial in Windows ... Permission error

Tags: python, pyserial

I am facing a problem when I open two devices in python using pySerial in windows. The code goes as follows :

```
 #dev1
dev1 = serial.Serial(
    port,
    baudrate=19200, 
    timeout=1,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)


dev2 = serial.Serial(
    port,
    baudrate=19200, 
    timeout=1,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)
```

Further when I run the program to read data from these devices, I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial_a.py", line 33, in <module>
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\serial\serialwin32.py", line 31, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\serial\serialutil.py", line 180, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM7': WindowsError(5, '
Access is denied.')
```

I run the program in the windows command prompt under Administrator Mode. Also, I do not face any problems when I run the same script on a Linux system. Can anyone suggest me a way to overcome this ?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290913/pyserial-error-5-access-is-denied

Comment: Thanks ... found the solution