denied access to com port 5
I am trying to write a python script that receives serial input from an Arduino (with servo and ultrasonic sensor) on com5 to plot a radar like graph. I have done everything I have found on forums making sure (the best I can) that nothing else like Arduino IDE is using the port (the serial monitor is closed) I've tried running it as administrator, I have restarted the computer. I have unistalled and reinstalled pyserial.
No Matter what i get this error:
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM5': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)

My Python code is:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
import time
import serial
import keyboard

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=2)

# setup the basic display window
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='k')
fig.canvas.toolbar.pack_forget()
fig.canvas.manager.set_window_title('Radar')
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.state('zoomed')

#setup the sub plot (the radar screen)  
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, polar=True, facecolor='green')
ax.tick_params(axis='both', colors='white' )
ax.xaxis.grid(True, color='grey', linestyle='--')
ax.yaxis.grid(True, color='grey', linestyle='--')
rmax = 100
ax.set_ylim([0.0, rmax])
ax.set_xlim([0.0, np.pi])
ax.set_position([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8 ])
ax.set_rticks(np.linspace(0.0, rmax, 5))
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
ax.set_thetagrids(np.linspace(0.0, 360, 17))

angles = np.arange(0, 360, 1)

#convert angles to radians
theta = angles * (np.pi / 180) 

pols = ax.plot([], linestyle='', marker='o', markerfacecolor='r', markeredgecolor='w', 
               markeredgewidth=1.0, markersize=3.0, alpha=0.5)
line1 = ax.plot([], color='w', linewidth=3.0)

fig.canvas.draw()
dists = np.ones((len(angles),))
axbbackground = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

while True:

    try:
        data = ser.readline()
        decoded = data.decode()
        data = (decoded.replace('\r','')).replace('\n','')
        #split data values (one distance, one angle) where there is a comma
        vals = [float(ii) for ii in data.split(',')]
        #check that there is in fact 2 values and it doesnt try plot an incomplete graph
        if len(vals) < 2:
            continue
        angle, dist = vals
        # can test working by adding 
        #print(angle, dist)

        #Create all angles into a list to plot all at once
        dists[int(angle)] = dist

        pols.set_data(theta, dists)
        #plot background
        fig.canvas.restore_region(axbbackground)
        ax.draw_artist(pols)

        #create sweeping line
        line1.set_data(np.repeat((angle*(np.pi/180)), 2),np.linspace(0.0, r_max, 2))
        ax.draw_artist(line1)    
        fig.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
        
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            plt.close('all')
            print('User to  quit the application')
            break

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        plt.close('all')
        ser.close()  # Always close the port after usage
        print("Keyboard interrupt")
        break

exit


My Arduino code is:
#include <Servo.h>

Servo micro_servo;

int pos = 0;

const int servo_pin = 7;
const int trig_echo_pin = 3;

float duration, distance;

void setup() {
  pinMode (servo_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (trig_echo_pin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  micro_servo.attach(servo_pin);
}

void loop() {
  // Sweep the servo from 0 to 180 degrees
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos++)
  {
    micro_servo.write(pos);
    delay(50);
    read_ultrasonic_distance(pos);
  }
    // Sweep the servo back from 180 to 0 degrees
  for (pos = 180;pos>=180; pos--)
  {
    micro_servo.write(pos);
    delay(50);
    read_ultrasonic_distance(pos);
  }
  delay(200);
}

void read_ultrasonic_distance(int angle)
{
pinMode(trig_echo_pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trig_echo_pin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trig_echo_pin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig_echo_pin, LOW);

  // Set the pin to input mode to receive the echo
  pinMode(trig_echo_pin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(trig_echo_pin, HIGH);  // Measure the duration of the echo pulse

  // Calculate the distance based on the duration
  distance = (duration * 0.0343) / 2;

  // Send the angle and distance to the Python program via serial
  Serial.print(angle);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(distance);
}


(Assuming this is Windows) With the Arduino plugged in, have you checked Device Manager and verified the port exists and its number? Can you open the port with another program like putty?

If this is Linux/Unix, did you check the permissions?  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/read-write-to-a-serial-port-without-root

Yes @001 I verified the com port exists and is the correct one on the windows device manager.

Have you used another serial monitor app like TeraTerm or Putty to check you can view the data printed to that COM port?

Which python are you using? Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290913/pyserial-error-5-access-is-denied? Maybe try 5 instead of 'COM5'?

@RokitanskyAschoff No I have not, thanks. This is the first time I am trying a project that communicates with com port! Will investigate how to do this thank you!
And using python 3. Cool will try just 5 and see if that works.
